# Enforce AES-256 to AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aes

**Disclaimer: I am fully aware that AES-128 is considered secure but we have wierd governmental requirements.**

We run a server that provides a websocket interface with our clients as an elastic beanstalk application on AWS. It has an application load balancer in front of it which handles the HTTPS termination. We have a strange requirement on our system where all channels need to have > 200 bits encryption.

When our clients (which are IoT devices) establishes the connection the agreed on encryption becomes AES-128 (because all security policies in AWS accepts AES-128 and the devices do to).

The only way to, on the server-side, enforce AES-256 is to use the classic load balancer and add the ciphers ourselves. However, the classic load balancer **does not** support websocket.

Is there any possible way of circumventing this? Or do we need to add our own encryption to our channel to fulfill the requirements.

Comment: Would a Network Load Balancer not work here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best you could do with an Application Load Balancer (ALB) is to configure it to use the FIPS **ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-Res-2020-10** security policy, however it will still be possible to negotiate **ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256** and **ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256**. [based on the table in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#describe-ssl-policies) which will allow AES-128 as encryption method.

Another option would be to put an WebSocket API Gateway [but the ciphers are pretty much the same](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version.html#apigateway-custom-domain-tls-version-regional-and-websocket) and you might need to deal with the [throttling in that case](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html) which is probably not the best thing to do considering the IoT clients.

Putting CloudFront in front of the ALB is not going to cut it either, as it has the same approach [and the ciphers in the security policies for it are essentially the same](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html#secure-connections-supported-ciphers)

The security policy of the Network Load Balancer (NLB) is actually the [same as the one of the ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-tls-listener.html#describe-ssl-policies).

Essentially all possible AWS services are relying on the same security policies.

Which leads us to the two final options:

- trying somehow to force it on client ends, which is most likely not possible
- or replacing the ALB with a Network Load Balancer (which supports WebSockets) as suggested by @Mark B, setting up TCP listeners on it and [handling the SSL yourself server side in your EB application which varies based on your application platform, but you should be able to enforce stricter (AES256) ciphers.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html)